# SQL Server : Table Variable Update

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a table variable in SQL Server that contains 3 columns of data that have been grouped by quarter. I have succeeded in selecting the appropriate data for each of the 3 columns but do not know how to update the contents of the table variable with each additional query.

Therefore, rather than having a table with 4 rows (one for each quarter) and 3 columns of data, I have 12 rows (4 quarters duplicated 3 times) and lots of nulls in the data columns.

How can I create the 4 row only version of the table with no NULLS?

Query:

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (oYear INT, oQuarter INT, chin FLOAT, press FLOAT, pull FLOAT)
DECLARE @sDate AS DATE, @eDate AS DATE, @athName AS VARCGAR(50), 
        @chin1RM AS FLOAT, @press1RM AS FLOAT, @pull1RM AS FLOAT;

SET @sDate = '2016-10-01';
SET @eDate = '2017-10-01';

SET @athName = 'Steve';

INSERT INTO @temp (oYear, oQuarter, chin)
    SELECT 
        DATEPART(YEAR, Day.Date), 
        DATEPART(QUARTER, Day.Date), 
        MAX(Pred1RMBMF) 
    FROM 
        GymLoad 
    JOIN 
        Session ON Session.id = GymLoad.SessionID 
    JOIN 
        Day ON Day.id = Session.DayID 
    JOIN 
        Athlete ON Athlete.id = Day.AthleteID 
    WHERE 
        (ExerciseID = 200 OR ExerciseID = 198) 
        AND FullName = @athName 
        AND Day.Date >= @sDate 
        AND Day.Date <= @eDate 
    GROUP BY 
        DATEPART(YEAR,Day.Date), DATEPART(QUARTER,Day.Date);

INSERT INTO @temp (oYear, oQuarter, press)
    SELECT 
        DATEPART(YEAR, Day.Date), 
        DATEPART(QUARTER, Day.Date), 
        MAX(Pred1RMBMF) 
    FROM 
        GymLoad
    JOIN 
        Session ON Session.id = GymLoad.SessionID 
    JOIN 
        Day ON Day.id = Session.DayID 
    JOIN 
        Athlete ON Athlete.id = Day.AthleteID 
    WHERE 
        (ExerciseID = 164 OR ExerciseID = 174) 
        AND FullName = @athName 
        AND Day.Date >= @sDate  
        AND Day.Date <= @eDate 
    GROUP BY 
        DATEPART(YEAR, Day.Date), DATEPART(QUARTER, Day.Date);

INSERT INTO @temp (oYear, oQuarter, pull)
    SELECT 
        DATEPART(YEAR, Day.Date), 
        DATEPART(QUARTER, Day.Date), 
        MAX(Pred1RMBMF) 
    FROM 
        GymLoad
    JOIN 
        Session ON Session.id = GymLoad.SessionID 
    JOIN 
        Day ON Day.id = Session.DayID 
    JOIN 
        Athlete ON Athlete.id = Day.AthleteID 
    WHERE 
        (ExerciseID = 183 OR ExerciseID = 183) 
        AND FullName = @athName 
        AND Day.Date >= @sDate  
        AND Day.Date <= @eDate 
    GROUP BY 
        DATEPART(YEAR, Day.Date), DATEPART(QUARTER, Day.Date);

SELECT * FROM @Temp
```

Current returned result set from the query:

```
oYear   oQuarter    chin    press   pull
------------------------------------------
2017    1          104.02   NULL    NULL
2017    2          102.22   NULL    NULL
2017    3          100.54   NULL    NULL
2016    4          104.3    NULL    NULL
2017    1          NULL     81.61   NULL
2017    2          NULL     71.26   NULL
2017    3          NULL     75.86   NULL
2016    4          NULL     80      NULL
2017    1          NULL     NULL    91.95
2017    2          NULL     NULL    68.97
2017    3          NULL     NULL    73.75
2016    4          NULL NULL    85.33
```

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregate by year and quarter and use an aggregate function (e.g. `MAX`) on the data columns to remove the nulls.

```
SELECT
    oYear,
    oQuarter,
    MAX(chin) AS chin,
    MAX(press) AS press,
    MAX(pull) AS pull
FROM @Table
GROUP BY
    oYear,
    oQuarter;
```